# Can I define one drawable selector for different color button?

Tags: android, android-button, android-drawable, android-selector

I want add some click effect to button, so I define a drawable b1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#cf00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#f00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And then I apply this to the button background

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/main_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn"
        android:background="@drawable/b1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
```

But there are over 20 different colors buttons in the app, I don't want to create many drawable for each button. If I use drawable in background, I cannot set background color to such button. If I use color in background, I cannot set drawable to such button.

Can I define a drawable only has pressed style? when the button pressed, add some transparent to the button. At the same time, I can define different color in each button.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the the theme of your app, assuming that all buttons will have a default/focused color that is the same and you only want the "pressed" state to vary.

Otherwise, selectors are the way that you define each of color/transparency option. There isn't a "shortcut" to use a group or array of selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited because of the way you are managing the alpha of the pressed color.  It's the same color, but with some transparency to allow the background color to blend in.  A good reason to do that would be if you have full color images underneath.  With twenty button colors, it's hard to see that being the case.

So, if you are using a solid background, then you could wrap each button in a FrameLayout.  Set the background color of each Frame layout to a button color. Set the button drawable to use #3xxx (where xxx=your bg color).  #3xxx of background blended onto your button would be the same as blending #C___ of your button color onto the background color (in hex F-3=C).  Set the normal state for the button drawable to transparent (@android:color/transparent) to allow the full color of the button to show though.